# openGL or UIKit ? what is the best ? which apps use openGl which apps use UIKit?

Tags: iphone, xcode, opengl-es, uikit, 2d

well I would like to know which famous games on the appstore (angry birds, tiny wings etc...) use opengl, which one use UIKIt .And then can you tell me what is the best for making 2D games ? Because some people say that the performance of UIKIT is not good, but I don't know how to code with openGL :/ Sorry for my english I'm french :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Cocos2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/):

> cocos2d for iPhone is a framework for building 2D games, demos, and
>   other graphical/interactive applications. It is based on the cocos2d
>   design: it uses the same concepts, but instead of using python it uses
>   objective-c.

you can check also this project: [Kobold2D](http://www.kobold2d.com/display/KKSITE/Home)

> Kobold2D is the easiest 2D game engine for Objective-C programmers.
>   Free & Open Source. For iPhone, iPod touch, iPad and Mac OS X.

**Edit:**

This [link](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/wiki/GamesUsingCocos2d) shows some games developed with cocos2D.

Comment: can you tell me some famous apps mad with cocos 2D or kobold 2D please ?

Comment: ok thank you now I understand. these are only very bad quality games that is why I 'll never use cocos2D thank you :)

Comment: @jeanbernard: these games may be bad quality, but it's because people make them bad quality, it is possible to achieve stunning applications with the right amount of skill.

Comment: i think this game uses cocos2d : itunes.apple.com/us/app/zombiesmash/id349095099?mt=8 and this game was #1 on the top paid charts for a while, just proves it's up to the developer